# Unable to export SVG of bpmn in VScode, Unknown FileSystem Error

Tags: visual-studio-code, svg, bpmn, kogito

I had created and executed a BPMN process using VSCode. I was able to run the process successfully.
But on trying to import the SVG, getting the following error
*Unable to write file 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\d:\Projects{mypath}\src\main\resources\Sample-svg.svg' (Unknown (FileSystemError): Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, mkdir 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\d:')*

Saw issue might be of write access, but unable to obtain it.
VSCode version: 1.64.2

Added all bpmn and java extensions needed.

Have also tried starting and running as admin, provided the app all required write permissions in app security, still no change.

Comment: Could you try running VSC in Administrator mode?

Comment: Tried that, as edited above, ran in admin mode, gave the app exclusive read and write permissions, no use @Neele22

Comment: Now that I look at it, your path looks quite strange. It seems as if VSCode is trying to find the "D:\..." path inside the "C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code" path

Comment: I am running my project in D:/, that shouldn't be an issue right? Projects shall be created in folders outside C @Neele22

Comment: Well, it seems that this error (mkdir 'c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\d:') tells you that it is trying to create the D: drive inside the microsoft VS Code folder on the C: drive. That can't be right.

Comment: So, is there some path i need to edit in VSCode? The project cannot be created inside C, so @Neele22

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242306/discussion-between-codeforharman-and-neele22).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in how NodeJS's `path.resolve` resolves a different drive path.

This is how the path where the SVG will be exported is defined:

```
const svgUri = editor.document.uri.with({ path: __path.resolve(svgFilePath, svgFileName) });
```

By default, the SVG is exported to `fileDirname`, which is the path where your BPMN file is. But in this case `path.resolve` is appending this path "c:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code".

A simple way to workaround/fix this is to go to your VSCode Settings and find the **Kogito > Bpmn: Svg File Path** settings and add a forward slash (**/**) before **"${fileDirname}"**, leaving the setting with the value: **"/${fileDirname}"**.

Or you can edit your VSCode's *settings.json* file, adding this property:

```
{
   ...
   "kogito.bpmn.svgFilePath": "/${fileDirname}"
}
```

[Kogito > Bpmn: Svg File Path setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Sl17.png)

Comment: Resolved my issue . Thanks a lot @Thiago

Comment: No problem! Hopefully, [this fix](https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-tools/pull/886) gets added in the next version :)